# Java heap space error when Heap hasn't expanded to max size

Tags: java, heap-memory, jvisualvm

I'm currently having a problem with my Eclipse IDE dying when it receives too much console output.

If I set "Run/Debug » Console » Console buffer size (characters)" too big, then I start getting "IOConsole Updater" errors citing "Java heap space" as the cause.

When I attach `jvisualvm` to the Eclipse process, I can see that "Used" keeps cycling, peaking ever closer to "Size" until it eventually falls over, what I don't understand is that "Size" never even gets close to "Max".

I've told the JVM (using `-Xmx2g`) to use up to 2GB (Max), but it's allocating 1GB (Size) and using between 300MB and 1GB (Used), yet returning "Java heap space" when the process briefly tries to go over that artificially low 1GB heap "Size".

What is causing this behaviour?

Why is "IOConsole Updater" (and sometimes "Trim Job") reporting "Java heap size" errors rather than causing the java heap to be expanded to the max size allowed?

---

Environment (thanks for the reminder @Dr Phil), from the `jvisualvm` overview page (with paths elided):

```
Host: localhost
Main class: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
Arguments: -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /.../eclipse473a_linux64_20180903//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.3.20180405-1200/splash.bmp -launcher /.../eclipse473a_linux64_20180903/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /.../eclipse473a_linux64_20180903//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so -startup /.../eclipse473a_linux64_20180903//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 205001f -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product -data /.../workspace -keyring /.../.eclipseauth/.keyring -showlocation -vm /.../java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-work

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.211-b12, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.8.0_211, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /.../java/x64/jdk1.8.0_211/jre
JVM Flags: <none>
```

Comment: are you using a 32 or 64 bit jvm ?

Comment: 64bit @DrPhil. I meant to mention this but forgot, question edited to add environment info.